# Couchbase N1ql query optimisation for date range

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I am using couchbase 6.0 community version and I have about 20 million records and trying to run the following query,

```
SELECT SUM(sales) as sales, SUM(salesWithOutTax) as salesWithOutTax FROM `someBucket` where weekStartDate >= 1583087400 AND weekEndDate <= 1598725800
```

Here start and end dates are epoch with range of 1 year

I have created the following index:

```
CREATE INDEX `dates_salesValues` ON `someBucket`(`weekStartDate`,`weekEndDate`,`sales`,`salesWithOutTax`)
```

The query is taking about 1 minute to return the response. Wanted to know how I can improve the index, or the way the query is done. Or if any other better way of doing range search queries.

Comment: Seems like a good index, according to the index advisor. What version of Couchbase Server are you running? How many records are typically returned? What is the use case?

Comment: Couchbase 6.0 community version. There are 20 million records. What I want to do is aggregation on attributes sales, salesWithOutTax over all the documents for 1 year duration and return the aggregated results as this: SELECT SUM(sales) as sales, SUM(salesWithOutTax) as salesWithOutTax FROM `someBucket` where weekStartDate >= 1583087400 AND weekEndDate <= 1598725800

Comment: Unfortunately there is no straight answer to this (unless we get the db and try out some options). But I think partial index (https://docs.couchbase.com/server/current/learn/services-and-indexes/indexes/indexing-and-query-perf.html#partial-index:~:text=Array%20Indexing.-,Partial%20Index,-Unlike%20relational%20systems) should help your case.